# Table entities not being serialized properly after upgrade to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 4.0.0

Tags: c#, azure, serialization, asp.net-web-api, azure-storage

I have a C#.NET Web API project that works with Azure Table Storage.  Some of the methods returns lists of various table entities.  Until I upgraded to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 4.0.0 everything worked just fine.  Now only the base properties (PartitionKey, RowKey,Timestamp, and ETag) are returned and my own custom properties are ignored, i.e., not serialized.

I note that in the [change log for Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 4.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/changelog.txt#L249) there is an entry that seems like it might have something to do with this:

- Tables: TableEntity is serializable via the ISerializable interface.

In response to this I tried decorating my table entity class with [Serializable] and my custom properties with [DataMember].  An example:

```
[Serializable]
public class UserGroup : TableEntity
{
    public UserGroup(String PartitionKey, String RowKey)
        : base(PartitionKey, RowKey)
    {
        this.PartitionKey = PartitionKey;
        this.RowKey = RowKey;
    }

    public UserGroup()
    {
    }

    [DataMember]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String ShortName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String LicenseGuid { get; set; }
}
```

Still, only the base properties are returned, and my custom properties (Name, ShortName, and LicenseGuid) and not included in the JSON response from the Web API method.

Any ideas?  (I'm going back to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 3.2.1 for now)

Comment: I just started testing Azure Storage and got the same problem. I will try to downgrade to 3.2.1 tomorrow and see if that helps. If it works I can maybe create a simple example app to send to "veudayab" according to the answer below.

Comment: I can confirm that all my properties also serialized correctly after downgrading to 3.2.1. I'm using the latest Web Api 2.1 (version 5.1.2).

Comment: I have exactly the same problem after updating the library to version 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has now been fixed in our latest release that you can grab from here - http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  I'll see if I can create a simple test case.  But my app went from working fine to not working at all just with an update to this version of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, and worked fine once again as soon as I dropped back to 3.2.1.  I'm pretty sure that Web API 2.1 is not properly serializing any responses that contain TableEntities.

Comment: I am also experiencing this (seemingly) exact issue. However, I'll hold off on providing code until I can confirm it's not a subtle error on my end.

Comment: I haven't tried the latest, but the changelog says "TableEntity does not support object serialization. If serialization logic is required for your entity, please implement the ITableEntity interface and serialization logic directly in your entity class."  So when you say it has been fixed what do you mean?  Is TableEntity serialization now working like it did in previous versions, e.g., 3.2.1?

Comment: Yes. It does work like it did in the previous versions. WebApi's JSON serializer should be able to serialize the data just fine. Please give it a try and let us know if you face any issues.

Comment: I can conirm that the 4.0.1 package works good without any changes. I just updated through NuGet and it works as before (at least for my simple application). Thanks for the fix!

Comment: I am using 4.0.1 and out of the box, classes derived from TableEntity fail to serialize because the TableEntity is not marked as serializable.  I presume given the comments on the 4.0.1 changelog I have to instead use ITableEntity, but this means essentially copying the TableEntity code into my own base class?