# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity is not marked as serializable using Storage 4.3.0.0

Tags: c#, azure, serialization

I am trying to move to Azure's Redis Cache, but I am getting

> Type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity' in Assembly
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.

when trying to serialize TableEntity or a class that inherits TableEntity.  This [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658625/table-entities-not-being-serialized-properly-after-upgrade-to-microsoft-windowsa) indicates the issue was fixed after 4.0.0 - any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Breaking Changes description](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/BreakingChanges.txt), this is intentionally removed and didn't come back:

> - Tables: Removed Serialized attribute and ISerializable implementation from TableEntity. Implement ITabeEntity for your custom
>     entities if you need either.