# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity is not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, redis, azure-storage

> Type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity' in Assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.

I am trying to use Redis Cache and when I try to serialize before storing the object I get the above error. I have searched it online but haven't found any solution.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the changelog for the Storage Client Library version 4.0.1:

`Tables: Removed Serialized attribute and ISerializable implementation from TableEntity. Implement ITableEntity for your custom entities if you need either.`

Please implement ITableEntity if you need the Serialized attribute.

Answer (score 0):

According to this, the issue has been fixed in current versions:

[Table entities not being serialized properly after upgrade to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage 4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658625/table-entities-not-being-serialized-properly-after-upgrade-to-microsoft-windowsa)

Comment: What version did you try with (newest, 6.0.0?) and was it the same error, or a new one? Could you update your question?