# Windows Azure Table Storage Serialization Error in Bot Framework v3

Tags: c#, .net, azure, botframework

I am using Windows.Azure.Storage .NET Client library (v 9.3.2) to work with Azure Storage Tables. I am using this in Bot Framework v3. Bot Framework requires all entity classes to be [Serializable].

My domain classes inherit from TableEntity and look like the following:

```
 [Serializable]
    public class FAQContent : TableEntity
    {
    public string Message
    {
        get;set;
    }
    public string Type
    { get; set; }

    public string Mime
    { get; set; }
```

On querying the Azure table, I am getting exceptions like the following:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableEntity' in Assembly 
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.2.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType
>   type)   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.b__0(MemberHolder
>   _)   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func2 valueFactory)   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type
>   type, StreamingContext context)   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Type
>   objectType, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext
>   context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter
>   converter, SerializationBinder binder)   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.WriteArray(WriteObjectInfo
>   objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, WriteObjectInfo memberObjectInfo)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo
>   objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object
>   graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, Object graph)   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.FormatterStore1.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IStore.Save(T
>   item)   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.ErrorResilientStore1.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IStore.Save(T
>   item)   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.FactoryStore1.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IStore.Save(T
>   item)   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.d__23.MoveNext()---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDialogTask.d__3.MoveNext()---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringEventLoop`1.d__5.MoveNext()---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.EventLoopDialogTask.d__3.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SetAmbientThreadCulture.d__3.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.QueueDrainingDialogTask.d__4.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.d__3.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.d__3.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.d__2.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializeByConversation.d__4.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.d__5.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.d__5.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LogPostToBot.d__3.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.d__11.MoveNext()---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.d__6.MoveNext()---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)   at Service_Bot.MessagesController.d__1.MoveNext()

Can someone suggest what could be going wrong?

Cheers
Abhishek

Comment: This probably isn't your issue, but avoid reserved keywords like 'Type' in your POCOs because they can cause issues with tooling an such. Use ContentType or FAQType instead.

Comment: I came across a similar issue [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23658625/table-entities-not-being-serialized-properly-after-upgrade-to-microsoft-windowsa] . However, no answers have been provided there as well.

Comment: This might be due to using `Windows.Azure.Storage .NET` for storage rather than [M`icrosoft.Bot.Builder.Azure`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#in-memory-data-storage) it requires some other changes to get working, but it'd be good to see some more code if help is needed on that front.